# Como hacer uso de las variables de int main(int number) en Windows usando un archivo por lotes

Tags: c++, batch

La pregunta es muy sencilla en realidad, pero el problema es que no pude encontrar una solución en internet, debido a que al plantear el problema y escribirlo no encontré lo que busco, solo otros resultados.

Escribí un programa simple como ejemplo (programa.exe):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int number)
{
    std::cout<<"Number="<<number<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

En linux normalmente lo único que tengo que hacer para asignar un valor a la variable `number` es escribir el nombre del programa y al lado poner el valor de la variable y el programa me muestra el valor de la variable, pero no me funciona en Windows, **¿como puedo asignar un valor a la variable "number" usando un archivo por lotes en Windows?**

Comment: ¿Qué compilador has usado? Ningún compilador de C++ debería aceptar `int main(int)` como firma válida para `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `main`, por defecto, tiene la siguiente firma:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
}
```

Donde:

- `argc`: Indica el número de parámetros con los que se invoca el programa. El valor mínimo para `argc` es 1.
- `argv`: Almacena cada parámetro por separado. Tendrá tantas cadenas de texto como indique `argc`. La posición 0 siempre indica el nombre del programa.

Es decir, si tu programa recibe un número, por defecto, se convertirá a texto y tu programa lo recibirá en `argv[x]` **como cadena de texto**:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  for( int i=1; i<argc; i++ )
    std::cout << "Number" << i << '=' << argv[i] << '\n';
}
```

Este es el mecanismo de entrada de parámetros estándar para C++, si usas cualquier otro mecanismo puede que te funcione en un Sistema Operativo o compilador determinado pero la solución no será portable, como estás comprobando.

**Nota:** Este mecanismo es independiente de la forma en la que se ejecute el programa: por consola, mediante script de batch, bash, sh, python y similares, por doble click, ... Este mecanismo viene reglado por el estándar del lenguaje.

Comment: Gracias, al fín una respuesta bien explicada y planteada.

Comment: Yo prefiero `for (auto begin = argv + 1, end = argv + argc; begin != end; ++begin)` para recorrer los argumentos :P

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster también podría haber usado `for( auto i : std::irange(1,argc))`... opciones hay para todos los gustos :)